# What is the difference between "afero" and "aĵo"?

Tags: word-difference

This topic was brought up but not answered below this question:
[Does Esperanto offer as many synonyms as English?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1970/does-esperanto-offer-as-many-synonyms-as-english)

Both "afero" and "aĵo" means thing, right? Is one abstract and the other concrete or is there some other way to separate them?

Answer (score 6):

I answered the question here:

https://www.duolingo.com/comment/9679034

Here are the relevant bits.

Q: Ĉu oni povas klarigi la [diferencon] inter "afero," "aĵo," kaj "objekto"?

A: Sen kontroli en vortaro, jen miaj pensoj.

- "Afero" estas la plej vastasence. Thing, matter, affair. Esperanto estas "la afero."
- "Aĵo" estas pli "fizika" ol afero, kaj pli nebula. Thing, thingy,
- "Objekto" estas fizika, kaj pli klara en la menso de la parolanto. Thing, object.

Comment: And don't forget about 'kozo': http://vortaro.net/#kozo